Hire K workers test case fail
Problem
You are given a 0-indexed integer array costs where costs[i] is the cost of hiring the ith worker.
You are also given two integers k and candidates. We want to hire exactly k workers according to the following rules:

You will run k sessions and hire exactly one worker in each session.
In each hiring session, choose the worker with the lowest cost from either the first candidates workers or the last candidates workers. Break the tie by the smallest index.
If there are fewer than candidates workers remaining, choose the worker with the lowest cost among them. Break the tie by the smallest index.

A worker can only be chosen once.
Return the total cost to hire exactly k workers.
Link to the problem
Logic
To have two minheaps the left and the right one.

Pop from both heaps and compare them. If left one is greater, input an added new one from the left, and push back the right element back to the heap
If right one is greater, add a new element from the array to the right heap, push back theleft element back to the left heap as it lost the tie
Keep adding the costs of the workers to the total_cost variable an return total_cost

Code
import heapq
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def totalCost(self, costs: List[int], k: int, candidates: int) -> int:
        left_h = []
        right_h = []
        N = len(costs)
        total_cost = 0
        left_idx = candidates - 1
        right_idx = N - candidates

        for i in range(candidates):
            heapq.heappush(left_h, costs[i])

        for i in range(right_idx, N):
            heapq.heappush(right_h, costs[i])

        i = 0
        while i < k:
            left_ele = heapq.heappop(left_h)
            right_ele = heapq.heappop(right_h)
            if left_ele <= right_ele:
                total_cost += left_ele
                heapq.heappush(right_h, right_ele)
                if left_idx + 1 < N and (right_idx == N or left_idx + 1 < right_idx):
                    heapq.heappush(left_h, costs[left_idx + 1])
                    left_idx += 1
            else:
                total_cost += right_ele
                heapq.heappush(left_h, left_ele)
                if right_idx - 1 >= 0 and (left_idx == -1 or right_idx - 1 > left_idx):
                    heapq.heappush(right_h, costs[right_idx - 1])
                    right_idx -= 1
            i += 1
        return total_cost

solution = Solution()
costs = [28,35,21,13,21,72,35,52,74,92,25,65,77,1,73,32,43,68,8,100,84,80,14,88,42,53,98,69,64,40,60,23,99,83,5,21,76,34]
k = 32
candidates = 12
print(solution.totalCost(costs, k, candidates))  # Output: 1407 # Expected: 1407

costs = [18,64,12,21,21,78,36,58,88,58,99,26,92,91,53,10,24,25,20,92,73,63,51,65,87,6,17,32,14,42,46,65,43,9,75]
k = 13
candidates = 23
print(solution.totalCost(costs, k, candidates))  # Output: 202  # Expected: 223

Issue
It fails the case given in the program.

left_idx is the index of the last inserted item on the left.
right_idx is the index of the last inserted item on the right.
If you run your program, left_idx=21 and right_idx=21 so you have inserted the same item into both heaps.
Change left_idx < right_idx to left_idx + 1 < right_idx.

that was a great catch. I did that now it fails on costs = [18,64,12,21,21,78,36,58,88,58,99,26,92,91,53,10,24,25,20,92,73,63,51,65,87,6,17,32,14,42,46,65,43,9,75] k = 13 candidates = 23

So it is a case of when there is an intersection of left_h and right_h while filling the initial heaps, so some elements are counted as duplicate.

Ok I figured it out. I filled the heap from 0 till min(candidates, N) whichever is smaller. and second filled the right heap from (max(right_idx), left_idx+1,N) so there are no duplicates at the start.
both left_h and right_h can get out of bounds if we run enough (k) times i think. So in the case of left_h or right_h being empty i set the left_ele or right_ele to float("inf") in hopes of it not being chosen. I am relying on the fact that they wont ask us to pick workers (k) more than available (len(costs))
